# How can I programmatically retrieve the version of Zig?

Tags: version, zig

How do I programmatically retrieve the version of [zig](/questions/tagged/zig)?. In [python](/questions/tagged/python) I could do it by using `sys` module.

```py
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
```

How can I achieve the same thing in [zig](/questions/tagged/zig)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`builtin.zig_version`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;builtin:zig_version). That returns [`SemanticVersion`](https://ziglang.org/documentation/master/std/#A;std:SemanticVersion).

```
const std = @import("std");
const builtin = @import("builtin");

pub fn main() !void {
    std.log.info("Zig version: {}", .{ builtin.zig_version });
}
```

Prints:

```
$ zig build run
info: Zig version: 0.12.0-dev.587+eb072fa52
```

Comment: Worth noting that the documentation recommends against using this for feature checking, which would be the main reason to check for the version. So this is pretty much only useful for debugging errors between different zig versions.

Comment: Still pretty helpful in the build.zig I'd say - example usage [in zls](https://github.com/zigtools/zls/blob/master/build.zig#L10)